# Quantum transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality, elementary-particles

In an atom, an electron absorbs a photon and jumps to a higher energy state. Thus the wavefunction for electron changes.

1.How does the photon interact with the initial wavefunction? How does this energy transfer take place?

2.Does the wavefunction change instantaneously or is there some time delay?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate, though I won't close your question unless you agree: [How do photons know they can or can't excite electrons in atoms?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/how-do-photons-know-they-can-or-cant-excite-electrons-in-atoms)

Comment: Also: [What is the Quantum Transition Time for Photon Emission?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142373/what-is-the-quantum-transition-time-for-photon-emission)

Comment: As Johns comment says , this is pretty much much answered in the dupes. The reason I am writing this to you is because I asked the same time of questions a few years ago and made the same (wrong) assumptions, that classical thinking could be applied, it can't in any way. Probability is involved, so we do an average of the time taken to transition and there may not (will not is better) be a smooth transition from one  orbit to the higher one, the shape of the transition orbital "bounces" all over the place in an unpredictable way until it settles down.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got the answer in the duplicates. Thanks